# Rails if elsif condition showing wrong section for a split second

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I have this condition to show the correct nav bar:

```
<% if current_user %>
    <% if current_user.quality? %>
        <%= render 'shared/quality_nav' %>
    <% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/nav' %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

On my production server everything is fine.  On my staging server, I see the quality nav bar for 1 second before the proper nav bar appears - I've never seen this happen before, what could be wrong?

**EDIT**

how quality is defined:

```
def quality?
    self.role == 'Quality' ? true : false
end
```

My only possible guess is the staging server is 1gb and no fast enough, but I find that odd.  Changing the code to this makes it go away, but I would still like to know why the original code caused that behaviour.

```
<% if current_user && current_user.quality? %>
    <%= render 'shared/quality_nav' %>
<% elsif current_user %>
    <%= render 'shared/nav' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is the definition of `quality?`?

Comment: Are you still facing the problem, I think staging server is not up and running properly.

Comment: try to print value of `current_user.quality?` on view